# Derived tensor product , independence of resolution

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, derived-functors, derived-categories

Right after [Lemma 20.26.13](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06Y7)

We have the following paragraph of how to derive the tensor product.

[image]

---

It  claims that the end result is independent of choice of K-flat resolution
Suppose we take $L^\bullet \rightarrow F^\bullet$, then we have to show a quasi iso.  $$Tot(G^* \otimes K^*) \simeq Tot(G^* \otimes L^*)$$

This would follow if we can exhibit a map $K^* \rightarrow L^*$ (or vice versa) and apply 20.26.13, but this is unclear to me.

---

What am I missing?

Some explaination would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\alpha_K:K^*\to F^*$ and $\alpha_L:L^*\to F^*$ are two $K$-flat resolutions of $F^*$.

As one typically proves when constructing the derived category (see Prop. 10.4.1 of Weibel's *Introduction to Homological Algebra*, for example) there is a complex $G^*$ with quasi-isomorphisms $\beta_K:G^*\to K^*$ and $\beta_L:G^*\to L^*$ such that $\alpha_K\beta_K$ and $\alpha_L\beta_L$ are chain homotopic.

Let $\gamma:M^*\to G^*$ be a $K$-flat resolution of $G^*$. Then $\beta_K\gamma:M^*\to K^*$ and $\beta_L\gamma:M^*\to L^*$ are quasi-isomorphisms of $K$-flat complexes, so you can now apply Lemma 20.26.13 of the Stacks Project.